# Maya: How do I get the filepath of a script that is loaded into the script editor?

Tags: python, maya

Hi fellow Maya Programmers!

I need some help figuring out a script's filepath from within maya using python. I have a certain script file located somewhere on my harddrive. Let's assume the file is called "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/test.py". In Maya's Script Editor I open the script file using "File" -> "Open Script..." Menu. A new Tab in my script editor appears, displaying the content of my test.py. What I am trying to do now, is run the test.py and print the folder location where that file (test.py) is stored.

Is there anyway to extract that path information?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. This does not work like this. You open the script and the script is copied into the maya python script tab. So it is now inside maya, not a textfile any more, even if the content is linked to the file and the file will be updated if you close the tab. What you can do is to import the script with

```
import yourscriptname as script
print(script.__file__)
```

To do so your script needs to be somewhere in the pythonpath.